# Convert html table to Json data and pass the data to ajax call in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

**I have to convert my HTML table to `json` data and pass it to the ajax call.** 
How to pass the `json` data as parameter in ajax.The data get passed if the value is string, it doesn't passed when it is in `json` format.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnSumbitTime').click(function () {        
              $('#result').append(JSON.stringify(makeJsonFromTable('tblSelectTime')))
                $('#result').show()
                alert(JSON.stringify(makeJsonFromTable('tblSelectTime')));
   This is my json data after converting from html table           
var selectedTime = "{[{\"Select\":\"\",\"FromTime\":\"\",\"ToTime\":\"\"},{\"Select\":\"\",\"FromTime\":\"11:02\",\"ToTime\":\"15:02\"}]}";

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '../AotuComplete.asmx/GetSeletedTime',
                    data: {SelectedTime: JSON.stringify(selectedTime) },
                    contentType: "application/j-son;charset=UTF-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    }
                })
            })
        });
 </script>
```

Comment: But something in JSON format *must* be a string by definition...

Comment: your contentType definition is wrong - there should not be be a `-` character

Comment: when you say "if value is string"...are you referring to the use of .stringify()? I think you have to do this probably when you're using legacy things such as ASMX services. If you used something modern such as Web API it wouldn't require it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following code snippet

```js
function submit(){
  var keys=[], arrayObj=[];
  $("#table thead tr th").each(function(){
    keys.push($(this).html());
  });
  
  $("#table tbody tr").each(function(){
    var obj={}, i=0;
    $(this).children("td").each(function(){
      obj[keys[i]]=$(this).html();
      i++;
    })
    arrayObj.push(obj);
  });
  $('body').append(JSON.stringify({yourObj: arrayObj}));
  return;//remove this line
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: your_url,
    data: JSON.stringify({yourObj: arrayObj}),
    contentType: "application/j-son;charset=UTF-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
       alert(response.d);
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
      <th>Expence</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
   <tr>
     <td colspan="3">
        <button onclick="submit()"> Submit</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

> Remove the return statement before ajax call and modify the ajax
>   statements. The json value shown when submit button is clicked will be
>   passed as the jsonstring in ajax call. You can modify the key and
>   values.